# I-Dislike-You Mode

Tags: grammar

If one would like to message something like

> I guess, you went into **I-dislike-you** mode.

What may seem a grammatical, and proper wording: To do this?

Comment: In an informal, conversational message, there's nothing at all wrong with your sentence, exactly the way you wrote it.

Comment: The message you've quoted is grammatical and fine the way it is. Using hyphenated phrases is an informal and sometimes humorous way of communicating.

Comment: You are misusing the verb **may seem**.  You want to ask "What *would be* a grammatical and proper wording?"

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure what you're asking, but I'm guessing you want to know how to convert "to do this" into something similar to the message you quoted.

If that is the case, you could say something like this:

> I am in *getting-things-done* mode.

The above means you're focused on accomplishing tasks.

> I am in *getting-this-done* mode.
>
> I am in *let's-get-this-finished* mode.

This means you're focused on this one particular task.